# VBA For next loop until last row of a column though not last row of sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to run a For Next Loop until the last row of a specific column (but not the last row of the sheet). So the first part of my list has data in column F and the second part doesn't. I only want the macro to apply to that first part. For some reason the loop only runs through the first part with certain commands but doesn't with the ones I am trying to do now. (I know it would be easy just to seperate the two parts manually and then run it but it drives me nuts not knowing what it is I did wrong :)).

This is the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim g As Double
g = 0.083333333
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("zm").Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("zm").Activate

For i = 2 To lastrow

    If Sheets("zm").Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("zm").Cells(i + 1, 1) And Sheets("zm").Cells(i, 5) = Sheets("zm").Cells(i + 1, 5) And Sheets("zm").Cells(i + 1, 6) - Sheets("zm").Cells(i, 7) < g Then
        Sheets("zm").Cells(i + 1, 7).Copy
        Sheets("zm").Cells(i, 7).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Sheets("zm").Rows(i + 1).Delete
    End If

Next i
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code is doing some checks on row i and, if necessary, copying a cell and deleting row i+1.  That deletion means that row i+2 now becomes row i+1, and row i+3 becomes i+2 ... and row lastrow+1 becomes row lastrow.  Your loop then starts doing stuff with the new row i+1 (which used to i+2) and keeps going until you get to row lastrow (which possibly started off being row lastrow+279).  You **may** need to do `For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1`, but I'm not sure whether that will work with your If statement.  (And this whole suggestion may be completely unrelated to your issue.)

Comment: LOL - I just noticed your userid - and I had just finished watching The Simpsons episode where Homer becomes Duffman

Comment: I would add some parenthesis to make sure your `If` is well clear, specially the third part

Comment: Haha, I barely even remember what happens in that episode, gonna have to watch it again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

avoid `Select`/`Selection` and/or `Activate`/`ActiveXXX`

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim g As Double
    g = 0.083333333

    With Worksheets("zm")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 1) And .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i + 1, 5) And .Cells(i + 1, 6) - .Cells(i, 7) < g Then
                .Cells(i + 1, 7).Copy Destination:=.Cells(i, 7)
                .Rows(i + 1).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So the "step -1" function subtracts a row from the loop with every time one is deleted, right?

Comment: You are welcome. The answer to your question is _Yes_ and _No_: 1) Yes; `Step -1` makes the loop iterator (`i`, in this case) _decrement_ by one, while the default loop behavior (i.e. without any `Step` specification) would _increment_ it by one.  2) No; the iterator update takes place at every loop regardless the `If....` condition is met and thus whether the row is deleted or not

Comment: Now I see. I didn't realize you could run the loop in the other direction. An easy and clever way to avoid the problem with the deleted rows, very helpful!